# “OnClick” action to asp.net dropdownlist item

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

My situation is a little strange I guess, suggestion of engineering is acceptable.

I have a DropDownList, on my "user" creation, called "city". When I'm creating the user I can create other city, but for this I have a button which redirect to other page.

So, ok. I've created the new City and now I click on my DropDownList of cities and guess what?! The field is not reloaded.

My first idea is every that I click on DropDownList, reload the data, but I can't find some OnClick action for Asp.Net DropDownList.

This is my question, some idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `AutoPostBack` option.  Set it to true and your page will automatically reload when the list is changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do. After the user creates the new city in the other page. Make sure that you refresh the parent page. This will bring the new city value.

HTH